# How to make all Windows 11 folders the same view type?

Tags: windows-11

Specifically, I want them to be "list" view.

I have tried clicking Options -> View -> Apply to Folders (button). It doesn't seem to do anything.

I have tried Properties -> Customize and checking "Apply this template to all subfolders". It doesn't seem to do anything. I have also tried both in succession, in case one depends on the other.

After doing those things, I go to any subfolder of the current folder and its view settings are still large icons (the Windows 11 default).

I'm also not in a "library"-- I know Windows acts weird with what it calls "libraries". I am in a regular old directory in my hard drive, "T:\tmp".

Comment: Pick a folder with lots of files and adjust that. Then try Apply to Folders again. It works for the most part here on Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: @John The folder I'm in does have a lot of files, but no, "Apply to folders" still does nothing.

Comment: Try running DISM  dism.exe  /online /cleanuo-image /restorehealth  followed by SFC  sfc /scannow   and then restart and test.